# plot pre-post data from a dataframe

Tags: python

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
      code  number  time
0   1.0     899     pre
1   5.0      81     pre
2   3.0       3     pre
3   4.0       3     pre
4   0.0       2     pre
0   1.0     806     post
1   5.0      90     post
2   3.0      75     post
3   0.0      13     post
4   4.0       6     post
```

I want a pre/post plot that looks like this:
[image]

Do you have any ideas on how I can achieve this?

I tried the following code:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1) 
ax.plot(df['time'], df['number'])
x_ticks_labels = ['pre','post']
ax.set_xticks(df['time'].unique())
ax.set_xticklabels(x_ticks_labels)
```

But the result doesn't look exactly like I want. Result:
[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fUR12.png)

Comment: Does each line only have two points? "Post" and "Pre"? If so, you'll need to pair the coordinates up first by splitting the dataframe. You can then set the xticks of the plot to be a list of strings using matplotlib, giving you an x-coordinate of "Post", and an x-coordinate of "Pre".

Comment: [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @ChaddRobertson I tried your suggestion as far as I understood. I've added the code and the result. But the result still doesn't look like I want. there is only one line, but should be 5, and there are also additional horizontal lines that I don't want

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Step one is to separate the pre and post data. I've not shown this, but it is as simple as referencing a column and then slicing it down the middle.

You then need to create a tuple for each pre-post pair; these are your y-coordinates. Your x-coordinates don't really matter, as they will simply be assigned a tag (either "Pre" or "Post").

The following script does this, however, note that the large relative magnitude of the first pair's values make it appear as though the other pair values remain relatively constant:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

p1 = [899, 81, 3, 3, 2]
p2 = [806, 90, 75, 13, 6]

pairs = list(zip(p1, p2))

codes = [1.0, 5.0, 3.0, 4.0, 0.0]

plt.figure(figsize=(8, 5))

for i, pair in enumerate(pairs):

    plt.plot(("Pre", "Post"), pair, label=f"code: {codes[i]}")
    plt.scatter(("Pre", "Post"), pair)

plt.legend(loc="center right")
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

This provides the following plot (aspect ratio set to 8:3 to avoid people scrolling for eons):

[image]

If you are more interested in showing the rate of change between the pre and post data, you can adjust each pair to be a value between 0.0 (the min value in the pair) and 1.0 (the max value in the pair), as shown below:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

p1 = [899, 81, 3, 3, 2]
p2 = [806, 90, 75, 13, 6]

pairs = list(zip(p1, p2))
pairs = [(pair[0] / max(pair), pair[1] / max(pair)) for pair in pairs]

codes = [1.0, 5.0, 3.0, 4.0, 0.0]

plt.figure(figsize=(8, 3))

for i, pair in enumerate(pairs):

    plt.plot(("Pre", "Post"), pair, label=f"code: {codes[i]}")
    plt.scatter(("Pre", "Post"), pair)

plt.legend(loc="center right")
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

Giving you the following:

[image]

This shows the difference between pre and post values nicely, but doesn't quite convey the magnitude difference. If the pairs are of different units, this can be solved by creating a secondary axis. I don't recommend this if your pairs share a unit, as this makes reading the plots more difficult. If you want to add a secondary axis, take a look at the link below:

https://matplotlib.org/3.5.0/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/secondary_axis.html

You can remove the x-axis gridlines by changing `plt.grid()` to `plt.grid(axis="y")`.

You can also explicitly set the color and scatter-point shapes (if you would prefer to exactly match the image style shown in your question).

Comment: You deserve that!